# how decrypt string openssl by pem in c#

Tags: c#, openssl, pem

i have few string from application develeoped with c++

i try unpack ( protected by themida/winlicense ) this exe (but 30-40% code can read only, all not reversed) , and now looking this application Encrypt and Decrypt with a Pem file and ssl with below detail :

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
base64_encoded_key
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

&&&

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
base64_encoded_key
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How can i find encrypt method ? i need decrypt/encrypt few string encrypted by this Exe.

Answer (score 0):

In .net 5 it looks to be built in now, [see](https://www.scottbrady91.com/C-Sharp/PEM-Loading-in-dotnet-core-and-dotnet) for examples.

In older versions of .net, your best to use a library like [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) to support pem files.